# Scott Pilgrim (Movie) - How did Gideon control Ramona?

Tags: scott-pilgrim

In the movie 'Scott Pilgrim vs. The World' in the final confrontation, Ramona is seated next to Gideon.  She expresses that she is under his control, I assume mentally as there were no restraints.

How did he control/suppress her?  Why does she not help Scott in the final battle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She was controlled by a [mind control chip](http://scottpilgrim.wikia.com/wiki/Gideon's_Microchip) of sorts.

[image]

From the wiki:

> Gideon's Microchip is a device seen only in Scott Pilgrim vs. the
>   World as a mind control device used on Ramona to follow Gideon's
>   commands whenever he's around (Breaking up with Scott, Telling Scott
>   that she was still with Gideon, etc.) and keeps her docile during
>   Gideon's first fight against Scott in the movie. It is implanted on
>   the back of her head and glows green when active.